# Error LNK2005 already defined on updating C++/Fortran solution to VS 2013

Tags: c++

I am trying to update a working C++ and Fortran solution from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013. When updated, the Win32 platform builds regularly but Win64 gives the following errors:

```
error LNK2005: __CIpow already defined in libmmt.lib(pow_stub.obj)  
error LNK2005: _pow already defined in libmmt.lib(pow_stub.obj)  
fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I have no idea why it only builds on Win32 or what I can do to fix this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild all dependencies with VS 2013?

Comment: It looks like you have a pow_stub.cpp that sould be excluded from compilation

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be helpful with so little detail to go on but here are some things to think about.

### Platform Dependent Code

It's not impossible that your code is at fault - for example you could perhaps have `#ifdef` code that depends on the platform being built.  That could mean your Win32 and Win64 builds are compiling different code.  But the fact your code builds successfully in Visual Studio 2010 suggests this is unlikely.

A variation of this might be a standard header which has changed between Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013 in some platform dependent way.  But again this doesn't seen likely - things aren't supposed to break just because you include a header.

### Platform Dependent Properties

A common source of build errors in multi-platform solutions is a difference in project settings for the two platforms.  Of course some properties are *supposed* to be different between Win32 and Win64 but others should be identical, or should be the "same" in the sense that they use the 32 and 64 bit versions of the same setting.

It's worth looking through all of your Project settings for unintended differences between the two platforms.  Since you are getting a linker error it might be especially worth examining the Linker's "Additional Library Directories" and "Additional Dependencies" settings.  Remember that x64 code must link to x64 versions of files - either by using a different file name or by linking to a file in an x64 specific directory.

One trick to looking for property variations is to open Project Properties and set "Platform" to "All platforms".  Then look for individual properties with a value of "<different options>".  **I think** this works in Visual Studio 2013, it certainly works in Visual Studio 2015 (sorry, I don't have VS 2013 installed anywhere convenient).

### Linker Diagnostics

Another potential approach is to turn on the [Linker /verbose option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6(v=vs.120).aspx) and compare the output of the Win32 and Win64 builds.  There will be a *lot* of output but you may be able to use "find" or a diff tool to look for differences in where/how `__CIpow` and `_pow` are linked that may give you a clue.  The bad news is it probably won't point directly at your problem's cause.  You'll have to work backwards from what the Linker is actually doing, combined with some detective work and experimentation to figure out what's actually happening.

### Breaking Changes

Another possibility since you are upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013 is Breaking Changes.  You'll have to work through the list of [Breaking Changes introduced in Visual Studio 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.110).aspx) and the list of [Breaking Changes introduced in Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.120).aspx) looking for  something that might produce the symptoms you are getting.

### Accidents

If you haven't already done so, you should confirm that the Visual Studio 2010 version of your solution builds successfully for both Wn32 and Win64.

Assuming it does, use your favourite diff tool to compare the .sln and .vcxproj files from the 2010 and 2013 versions.  Look for changes that don't seem to make sense in the current context.  It's always possible that something got changed inadvertently.

Finally, if you have a system with both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013 installed, you could use the [Platform Toolset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576(v=vs.120).aspx) property to use Visual Studio 2013 to build your project with the Visual Studio 2010 toolset.  If you find that the solution compiles and links successfully using with the 2010 (v100) toolset but fails with the 2013 (v120) toolset that may tell you something.